# PrimeFaces: selectOneButton is cleared on validation error

Tags: primefaces

I have a wizard tab and a few fields in it. Some of them are required.
There is also a `selectOneButton`. The problem is when I have some required fields empty **and** some value selected in `selectOneButton` - when the validation fails on form submit, it gets "unclicked", i.e. nothing is selected. I suspect that the whole form gets updated but other components still hold the visible value.
What am I doing wrong or maybe someone have had the same problem?
I use PrimeFaces-5.0.RC2

Here is the code:

```
<p:tab title="Service params" id="firstTab">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                Name *
                <p:inputText value="#{serviceMB.service.name}" label="Name" required="true" maxlength="150"/>

                                Unit
                                <p:selectOneButton value="#{serviceMB.service.unit}" converter="serviceUnitConverter"
                                   filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" label="Unit"
                                   id="unitMenu"
                                   required="true">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{serviceMB.allServiceUnits}" var="unit"
                                   itemLabel="#{unit.name}"
                                   itemValue="#{unit.code}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                            update=":addServiceForm:priceListPanel"
                            process="@this"/>
                </p:selectOneButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
<p:commandButton value="Next" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-e" iconPos="right" type="button" onclick="PF('serviceWizard').next();"/>
```

So **Unit** is the component which value is cleared. I really have no idea why, so I moved to `selectOneMenu` instead which is less preferable in my case.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well what can I try in such a situation? I have a concrete problem, are you willing to help? As a temprorary option I had to use `selectOneMenu` component as it works fine.

Comment: Provide your code, we can't just simply provide a full working code/example based on your description. as a matter of fact your example is so simple and it's not a common bug/issue that could be solved only based on a text description.

Comment: Seems that I've found someone with similar problem: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17094. Unfortunately no solution too...

Comment: I've created an issue for that https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7346